# Extended WPF Toolkit RichTextBox display text vertically

Tags: wpf, binding, richtextbox, toolkit

I'm trying to bind a rich content (RTF format) to a rich text box (of Extended WPF Toolkit) via its Text property like this

```
<extToolkit:RichTextBox x:Name="rtbKIContent" Margin="8,8,8,8" 
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable}"
                                    Text="{Binding Content}">
                <extToolkit:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
                    <extToolkit:RtfFormatter></extToolkit:RtfFormatter>

                </extToolkit:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
                <extToolkit:RichTextBoxFormatBarManager.FormatBar>
                    <extToolkit:RichTextBoxFormatBar />
                </extToolkit:RichTextBoxFormatBarManager.FormatBar>
</extToolkit:RichTextBox>
```

Sometimes it works just fine, but there are circumstances that they just display the text vertically like this.

[image]

I don't know what's wrong with it...What should I do to make it display text from left to right like normal?

Comment: Did you try setting a fixed width to the RichTextBox?

Comment: Here is a similar question, having a working solution.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886337/richtextbox-showing-texts-vertically

Answer (score 5):

If you add a width to the RichTextBox, it should fix it.

I did this so it binds to the parent.

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

Note you will have to determine **AncestorType** for you. But you can do this too. Width="100"

Answer (score 2):

Agree with "jmogera".
Need to set width for this issue.

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="100"
```

You can set MinWidth to 100 and keep HorizontalAlign to streach if you want control to resize.

Comment: This one helped me a lot. I have the same issue but no anymore. This one should be the answer.